# Should I set AssemblyConfigurationAttribute?

Tags: .net, assemblyinfo

Is it good practice to set `AssemblyConfigurationAttribute` in .Net assembly files?

Comment: It doesn't matter what you set it to, "Retail" or "Release" would be logical choices.  Microsoft doesn't use it in their own assemblies.

Comment: I agree, in earlier versions of .NET/MSDN documentation they told you it is optional but should/could be set to debug or retail, but in the current documentation there is almost nothing about it. Sounds depreciated to me.

Answer (score 4):

I have not found this to be particularly useful (since none but the most low-level tools display this information) and I have never seen it used in production code I have worked on.

Regardless, if you want it, just add the following lines to your AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
#if DEBUG
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Debug")]
#else
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Release")]
#endif
```

Comment: I'd actually replace `#else` with `#elif RELEASE`. It doesn't seem right that anything non-`DEBUG` is automatically considered `RELEASE`. And if, for some reason, both preprocessor symbols are undefined, then it seems only proper not to emit the custom attribute at all.